# RoR - Link_to with nested hash from an each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, parameters

Having some trouble with nested hash parameters. Product has many features. Say product 1 has features foo and baz.

I'd like to pass both the product and all of the features to query string parameters in a link_to so that it ends up looking like this:

"/puppies/new?features%5Bbaz%5D=qux&features%5Bfoo%5D=bar&product=1"

I am currently trying this, which gets a syntax error for reasons that are probably obvious to people that are not me.

```
<% Product.each do | product | %>
  <%= link_to(new_puppy_path(product: product, features: { product.features.each 
    { | feature| feature.name : 'feature.'} } ), class: 'slorp') do %>
    // stuff inside the link
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea what I'm doing stupid here?

UPDATE: I have updated the code to:

`<%= link_to(new_puppy_path(product: product, features: product.features.each{|feature| {feature.name.to_sym =>` `feature.feature_colors.first}}), class: 'image') do %>`

This is much closer, as my output URL is now:

/puppies/new?features%5B%5D=3&features%5B%5D=2&product=2

I am just missing the name of the feature in-between the %5B and %5D - not sure why the feature name is not showing up.

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: feature.name : 'feature.' - i can't get that's this code supposed to output?

Comment: The goal is to output the params as in the URL above the code snippet - %5Bbaz%5D=qux. Updated with something new I have tried that works a bit more but still missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **map** instead of **each**. **Each** returns the original array itself on which it is operating. While **map** returns the elements from the block.

Comment: Awesome. This worked, too, and is what I will use moving forward. Thanks very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Pulled creating the hash up into the model:

```
def reco_features
  list = Hash.new
  feature_colors.each do |feature_color|
      list[feature_color.feature.name] = feature_color.id
  end
  return list
end
```

Then updated the link_to:

```
<%= link_to(new_puppies_path(product: product, features: features.reco_features ), class: 'slorp') do %>
```

Not sure why the inline wasn't working, but this fixed it. Required some additional context outside of the initial question, which I did not realize at the time. Apologies and thanks to all.